# SQL injection error with backslash

Tags: sql-injection

I've been trying to search for an explanation here and on google for some real answer, but havent found any thread so here it goes..

Im trying to inject some vulnerable code into a parameter on my dummy server, however the sanitation works fine, so it does not give an error with ' or '' 
after the id `login.asp?id=` however, when i just use \ to inject after the id parameter, it gives the following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

    [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.47]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'' at line 1

    /usr/login.asp, line 31
```

Is this a false positive? How can it give an error with a backslash and not while i use either ' '' 1=2 etc only with the blackslash..
Can someone explain why this happens and can an attacker exploit this, because i manually tried to exploit it but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you show us the query you are trying to spoof?  Hopefully you are not planning to hack someone /:~|

Comment: Post your server code as well, may be something in there